# Use loop in GSAP for taking multiple object's

Tags: javascript, gsap

Ho everyone ..

I was wondering is it possible to use loop in **GSAP** or maybe it have a something special for this situation's.

In my situation I have `ul` element with **30** `li` item's.

I want to give them individual animations which be increased.

For example like this

```js
TweenMax.to($(".blue"), 1,{x:100,y:50},"+=1")
TweenMax.to($(".red"), 1,{x:10,y:50},"+=1")
TweenMax.to($(".purple"), 1,{x:80,y:10},"+=1")
TweenMax.to($(".green"), 1,{x:35,y:70},"+=1")
```

```css
ul li {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  
  <li class="blue">1</li>
  <li class="red">2</li>
  <li class="purple">3</li>
  <li class="green">4</li>
</ul>
```

Like you use from snippet below there are **30** `li` item's with icon's and when window onload this icon's are spread to any random position that choosed by `Js`.

How to organize this code with loop.

Try 1. **forEach loop**

```
let liItems = document.querySelectorAll("li");

[...liItems].forEach((items) => {
    TweenMax.to(items, 1,{x:35,y:70},"+=1")
}
```

This didn't worked.

Try 2 **for Loop**

```
let liItems = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for(let i = 0;i < liItems.length;i++){
   TweenMax.to(liItems[i], 1,{x:35,y:70},"+=1")
}
```

Also didn't worked for me.

**Please help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (you might have to mess with the random number high value a little bit ...

```
const randomNum = (low, high) => {
  const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1)) + low;
  return r;
};

let liItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');

liItems.forEach(items => {
  TweenMax.to(items, 1, { x: `${randomNum(0, 180)}`, y: `${randomNum(0, 100)}` });
});
```

Comment: OMG this is awesome ty you +1 by me